# flutter webview net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

flutter webview net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
please note that the problem shown with the release not the debug

```
 WebView(
  initialUrl: widget.url,
  onPageFinished: (data){
    updateLoadingState(false);
  },
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  onWebViewCreated: (webViewController){
    _webViewController = webViewController;
  },
)
```

Comment: sounds like a server issue or a DNS issue, does url work in browser with mobile data?

Comment: yes it's work on chrome

Answer (score 2):

This error usually occurs when you are testing with the emulator or when your internet connection is poor.
If you are running your app on an emulator and you encounter this problem, trying running the app on a real device.
If the error persists, add internet permission to your android manifest.